# change default tramp path for finding files

Tags: key-bindings, tramp, sudo

I found the following code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7043786/6382059),

```
(defun sudo-find-file (file-name)
  "Like find file, but opens the file as root."
  (interactive "FSudo Find File: ")
  (let ((tramp-file-name (concat "/sudo::" (expand-file-name file-name))))
    (find-file tramp-file-name)))
```

But it tries to find the file is sudo mode in the current directory and I have to delete so many characters to reach root directory `/`.

How can I define the default opening path in the mentioned code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here an example with "/" as default directory:

```el
(defun sudo-find-file (file-name)
  "Like find file, but opens the file as root."
  (interactive
  (list (read-file-name "sudo Find File: " "/")))
  (let ((tramp-file-name (concat "/sudo::/" (expand-file-name file-name))))
    (find-file tramp-file-name)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use double slashes `//`. In the local case, a double slash in the minibuffer means to start at the root directory. In the remote case, a double slash in the minibuffer means to start at the root directory of the remote machine.

See the discussion in the Tramp manual, section "File name completion".